# Finding children elements that are missing unique keys? (reactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have this bit of code, that is working, but it is throwing a Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

```
Check the render method of `TopMenuDropdown`. See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
MenuItem@http://localhost:3000/protis-react/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:2815:110
TopMenuDropdown@http://localhost:3000/protis-react/static/js/main.chunk.js:2432:5
div
div
App@http://localhost:3000/protis-react/static/js/main.chunk.js:63:5
Router@http://localhost:3000/protis-react/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:174391:30
BrowserRouter@http://localhost:3000/protis-react/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:174011:35
```

at me. I am not even sure where to track down what is missing a key, or where I missed putting it in. Any way for me to track it, or is someone here able to find the missing elements that need the unique keys. I tried to put a key on almost anything I generated originally, but I'm not sure what went wrong where, and this has been bothering me.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Menu, MenuButton, MenuDivider, MenuItem, SubMenu} from '@szhsin/react-menu';
import '@szhsin/react-menu/dist/index.css'

const tooltipStyle = {
    position: "absolute",
    pointerEvents: "none",
    backgroundColor: "#D7D7A6",
    border: "1px solid",
    padding: "1px 8px",
    whiteSpace: "nowrap",
    zIndex: 200
};

class TopMenuDropdown extends React.Component {

    state = {
        pos: {x: 0, y: 0},
        tooltip: '',
        show: false
    };

    createTooltip = (tooltip) => ({
        onMouseEnter: ({clientX, clientY}) => {
            this.setState(
                {
                    pos: {x: clientX, y: clientY},
                    tooltip: tooltip,
                    show: true
                }
            );
        },
        onMouseLeave: () => {
            this.setState(
                {
                    show: false
                }
            )
        }
    });

    handleSelect = ({value}) => {
        this.props.onClick(value);
    }

    renderMenuItem(menuAnchor, menuItems, isSubMenu) {
        if (isSubMenu) {
            return (
                <SubMenu key={menuAnchor.id}
                         label={
                             <div
                                 key={menuAnchor.id}
                                 {...this.createTooltip(menuAnchor.attributes.title)}
                             >
                                 {menuAnchor['#text']}
                             </div>
                         }
                >
                    {this.menuGeneration(menuItems, menuAnchor)}
                </SubMenu>
            );
        }

        return (
            <>
                <Menu
                    style={{display: 'flex', float: 'left'}}
                    key={menuAnchor.id}
                    menuButton={
                        <MenuButton
                            key={menuAnchor.id}
                            {...this.createTooltip(menuAnchor.attributes.title)}>
                            {menuAnchor['#text']}
                        </MenuButton>}
                    onChange={({open}) => !open && this.setState({show: false})}
                >

                    {this.menuGeneration(menuItems, menuAnchor)}
                </Menu>
                {this.state.show && (
                    <div
                        key={menuAnchor.id}
                        style={{
                            ...tooltipStyle,
                            left: this.state.pos.x,
                            top: this.state.pos.y
                        }}
                    >
                        {this.state.tooltip}
                    </div>
                )}
            </>

        );
    }

    menuGeneration(menuItems, menuAnchor) {

        if (menuItems === undefined) {
            return <></>;
        }

        if (!Array.isArray(menuItems)) {
            menuItems = [menuItems];
        }

        return (
            menuItems.map(({a, attributes, ul}) => {
                    if (ul !== undefined && ul.li !== undefined) {
                        return (
                            this.renderMenuItem(a, ul.li, true)
                        );
                    }

                    if (a === undefined) {
                        return (
                            <MenuDivider key={menuAnchor.id} />
                        )
                    }

                    return (
                        <MenuItem
                            key={menuAnchor.id}
                            value={a.attributes.id}
                            onClick={(id) => this.handleSelect(id)}
                            {...this.createTooltip(a.attributes.title)}
                        >
                            {a['#text']}
                        </MenuItem>)

                }
            )
        )
    }

    render() {

        if (!this.props.topMenu.hasOwnProperty('ul')) {
            return null;
        }

        const menuItemRendering = this.props.topMenu.ul.li.map(({a, ul}) => {
            return this.renderMenuItem(a, ul.li, false);
        });

        return (
            <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
                {menuItemRendering}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default TopMenuDropdown;
```

Answer (score 4):

Issue is in `renderMenuItem` in the "else" branch when you render `Menu` and a `div` into a Fragment. When mapping JSX a React key needs to be on the ***outermost*** returned mapped element, the `Fragment` in this case.

```
renderMenuItem(menuAnchor, menuItems, isSubMenu) {
  if (isSubMenu) {
    return (
      <SubMenu
        ...
      >
        {this.menuGeneration(menuItems, menuAnchor)}
      </SubMenu>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Fragment key={menuAnchor.id}> // <-- add missing React key here
      <Menu
        ...
      >
        {this.menuGeneration(menuItems, menuAnchor)}
      </Menu>
      {this.state.show && (
        <div
          ...
        >
          {this.state.tooltip}
        </div>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: I edited the section, and added <React.Fragment key={menuAnchor.id}> instead of <> to encase that section, however, that did not solve the issue

Comment: @VladSD Can you create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the error for us to inspect and live debug. It might just be the case that you are rendering sets of sibling components and gave them identical keys, such as is the case with `Menu` component and the `div` when `this.state.show` is true, they both use `key={menuAnchor.id}`. React keys must be unique amongst all sibling components/elements. I don't know if you need to provide a key to nearly element (I don't think you do), so try removing all the "nested" keys you added, keeping only the ones on the outermost nodes being mapped.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `key={menuAnchor.id}` with `key={a.id}` for items directly in menuGeneration:

```
if (a === undefined) {
  return <MenuDivider key={a.id} />
}

return (
  <MenuItem
    key={a.id}
     value={a.attributes.id}
     onClick={(id) => this.handleSelect(id)}
     {...this.createTooltip(a.attributes.title)}
  >
    {a['#text']}
  </MenuItem>
)
```

Comment: This did not do anything that I can see, error persists